# How to make Kik video message show a thumbnail that fills the message box

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, kik

We would like to get our thumbnail images to fully fill the Kik message bubble the way other Kik video apps do (see image below). On iOS we are sharing like this:

```
KikMessage * msg = [KikMessage articleMessageWithTitle:nil
                                                  text:@"Check out this video I found"
                                            contentURL:self.video.shortURL
                                            previewURL:self.video.thumbnailURL];
```

However, the result is a small thumbnail image on the left of the Kik message box, and then the article text at right. Can anyone advise how to have only an image preview that fills the entire message box?

[image: Kik video share]

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the 'photo' layout message style.

Try using

```
KikMessage *message = [KikMessage photoMessageWithImageURL:self.video.shortURL
                                                previewURL:self.video.thumbnailURL];
```

Note that the behavior will be slightly different as you are sharing from another native application, whereas "Video Kik" and "Video For Kik" are Kik optimized webpages (see [dev.kik.com](http://dev.kik.com) for more details)

Comment: We tried this, but `photoMessageWithImageURL` doesn't seem to work to bring users to video content, only images. Video Kik and Video For Kik both have Kik web apps that work in combination with an iOS native app. That's how our app is designed to work as well. Can you advise on the right sequence of events to share and get the same results as those two apps?